# Failing to read a named pipe being written to

Tags: ruby, named-pipes

I have a stream of data that I’m writing to a named pipe:

```rb
named_pipe = '/tmp/pipe' # Location of named pipe
File.mkfifo(named_pipe) # Create named pipe
File.open(named_pipe, 'w+') # Necessary to not get a broken pipe when ⌃C from another process later on

system('youtube-dl', '--newline', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqz-KE-bpKQ', out: named_pipe) # Output download progress, one line at a time
```

Trouble is, while I can `cat /tmp/pipe` and get the information, I’m unable to read the file from another Ruby process. I’ve tried `File.readlines`, `File.read` with seeking, `File.open` then reading, and other stuff I no longer remember. Some of those hang, others error out.

How can I get the same result as with `cat`, in pure Ruby?

Note I don’t have to use `system` to send to the pipe (`Open3` would be acceptable), but any solution requiring external dependencies is a no-go.

Comment: `read` / `readlines` return the entire file so they block until the process is done writing. You have to use a method that reads one line at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like `File.readlines/IO.readlines`, `File.read/IO.read` need to load the whole temp file first so you don't see any be printed out.

try `File#each/IO.foreach` which process a file line by line and it does not require the whole file be loaded into memory

```rb
File.foreach("/tmp/pipe") { |line| p line }
# or
File.open('/tmp/pipe','r').each { |line| p line }
```

Comment: `open` also has a block form: `File.open('/tmp/pipe') { |file| ... }`